# Execute persistent powershell using Process (.net core)

Tags: c#, powershell, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a persistent powershell Process using the Process class in c#. Why ? for my particular scenario, as i am in .net core, we noticed that some third app connection were not supported by the powershell API.

I have the following class :

```
namespace Infrastructure.Repositories
{
    public class PowershellRepository : IPowershellRepository, IDisposable
    {
        Process process;
        private readonly string _scriptsPath;

        public PowershellRepository()
        {
            _scriptsPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

            process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
        }

        public string ExecuteCommand(string command)
        {
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = $@"& {command}";
            process.Start();

            var errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            return string.Concat(errors, "\n", output);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            process.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Which I used to pass simple powershell command and return the errors or the results.
My issue is that I need to be able to connect to other services, and be able to send command specific at this service, for example using ExchangeOnlineManagement, or Msol.
Right now, i can connect, but my second command will fail, probably because the process is either disposed, or because the session is not persistent.

Any idea how to achieve my goal ?

Comment: "we noticed that some third app connection were not supported by the powershell API" I don't understand what this means.

Comment: I agree with @IanKemp, you should explain your original problem. Maybe there is a better solution. This could be a [xy question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: With the Powershell API, in .net core, we couldnt connect to azure graph api / exchange, which is one of our requirements. This is why we decided to proceed like my code above. Ideally i could use the Poershell api, and use sessions i believe but it doesnt seem possible.